# Scrapy Splash takes forever to render a website

Tags: scrapy-splash

I am having a hard time scraping JS-loaded content (the product images) from [this website](https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/product/f21/sale/2000330946)

I have tried everything they recommend in the [FAQ] (https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html).
Eg:
- add wait
- disable private mode
- set timeout resource
but it's still not working.

Here's the coding i am using at the moment.
I try to wait for the images to load using a `while` loop but still no luck

```
function main(splash)
    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    splash.indexeddb_enabled = true
    splash:set_user_agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36')
    splash:set_viewport_size(1366, 768)
    splash.resource_timeout = 30
    -- why assert throws exception
    -- assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    -- assert(splash:wait(30))
    -- splash:set_viewport_full()

    -- wait for imgs to load
    sel = 'ul#imageButtonList > li:last-child'
    while not splash:select(sel) do
      splash:wait(0.1)
    end

    return {
      html = splash:html(),
      -- png = splash:png(),
    }
end
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?